chrony conflicts with time-daemon
I was trying to install freeipa-client on ubuntu 20.04 that will be used on a client with no apt access. I mannualy installed all the required .deb using dpkg.
after I successfully installed the freeipa-client v.4.8.6, I ran the ipa-client-install it produces this
This program will set up FreeIPA client.
Version 4.8.6

WARNING: conflicting time&date synchronization service 'ntp' will be disabled in favor of chronyd

Error checking LDAP: Operations error: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090CF4, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v4563
Discovery was successful!
Do you want to configure chrony with NTP server or pool address? [no]: no
Client hostname: ipa.mydomain.co.id
Realm: MYDOMAIN.CO.ID
DNS Domain: mydomain.com
IPA Server: server.domain.co.id
BaseDN: dc=mydomain,dc=co,dc=id

Continue to configure the system with these values? [no]: yes
Synchronizing time
No SRV records of NTP servers found and no NTP server or pool address was provided.
Using default chrony configuration.
CalledProcessError(Command ['/bin/systemctl', 'restart', 'chronyd.service'] returned non-zero exit status 5: 'Failed to restart chronyd.service: Unit chronyd.service not found.\n')
The ipa-client-install command failed. See /var/log/ipaclient-install.log for more information

I noticed that it demands chrony so I tried to install chrony_3.5-6ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb manually also using dpkg.
This time it has conflicts like this
dpkg: regarding chrony_3.5-6ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb containing chrony:
 chrony conflicts with time-daemon
  systemd-timesyncd provides time-daemon and is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive chrony_3.5-6ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing chrony
Errors were encountered while processing:
 chrony_3.5-6ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb

Any idea on how to deal with this? Thanks heaps!

You can try removing systemd-timesyncd if you know what you are doing because based on the provided logs, it just state that chrony isn't installed properly due to a package conflict.
Hope this helps!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
